# UK tax self assessment:- how to report currency gains from between when a cheque is issued and cashed?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, foreign-exchange, foreign-income

Can anyone tell me what should happen when a delay between foreign income arising and being converted into sterling results in an extra gain from the exchange rate?

For example:

A USD cheque is issued in July, but not cashed into £ until October. In the intervening months a change in the $/£ rate means that it cashes for £100 more than the £ value at date of issue. I.e. the $ cheque was worth £1000 in July, but £1100 by October.

On the arising basis HMRC guidance is to use the exchange rate from the date the income arose (July - £1000).
How then should I report the additional £100 gain (or equivalent loss)?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/manuals/rdrmmanual/rdrm31190.htm Check here

Comment: Thank you for the link, but that guidance refers to the remittance basis.
I am on the arising basis, on which HMRC guidance is very clear to use the exchange rate on the date the income arose.
However I have been unable to find guidance relating to the sort of gain described above.  
I think perhaps I should treat it as a capital gain on foreign currency, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: @CC8899 you don't need to worry about small capital gains of £100 or so unless you have exceeded your  £11,100  CGT allowance

Comment: Thanks.  You are right that if its a capital gain I won't have to pay anything so long as its under my allowance.  I might still need to fill in the capital gains section of my tax return though (without answering the individual questions): https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/work-out-need-to-pay

Answer (score 4):

It's not definitive, but it's a similar situation to the one I posted about in my question [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10831/tax-due-on-foreign-exchange-element-of-share-option-program). As you can see from my own answer, when I rang HMRC the guidance was to declare the additional value of the money in the "any additional information" box at the end of the tax return. That is what I did and nothing ever came of it - they never asked for more tax.

In your shoes I would enter the numbers on the return as the date the income arose and then make a note in the additional info box that it arose on X date, you cashed it on Y date, and the two values so that they can take that into account if they want to.

I also think that @Pepone is correct in the comments above that it would count as a capital gain, so unless you have exceeded your allowance it wouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Thinking it over it does seem increasingly likely that this would be a small capital gain.  I will take on board your idea of including all the relevant info in the extra space.

Comment: @CC8899 [My answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/80732/35567) (and the links to HMRC in it) to a slightly related question may be of interest / help. There a property was sold, but funds couldn't be converted immediately. Essentially, there are probably two taxable events: one on receiving the money (valued at the then current rate of exchange) and another on conversion (where any currency gain would be CGT).