# Do I pay tax on a gain made from a currency exchange following a house sale in USA

Tags: united-kingdom, foreign-exchange, capital-gain

I bought a house in the US in about 2010 and used it as a holiday home for my family (it was never rented out).

In around 2013 I sold the house, which after paying the estate agents fees and leaving furniture in the house I made a slight loss on.

I had to jump through hoops with the IRS before they would release all of the money from the sale (they withheld around 20 % of the sale proceeds until I put in a tax return the following year). As I was awaiting all the proceeds to be released I left the whole amount I got from the sale in a US bank. About 1 year later I recovered the withheld amount but then had difficulties in the US bank transferring the amount to my UK about.

Anyway to cut along story short **I bought dollars when the rate was good (at around $1.90 to £1) and sold (in 2016) after Brexit vote (rate of about $1.25 to £1).**

Do I have to pay tax for the gain I have made, if I do will if be capital gains tax and at what rate.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: This is one of those rare cases that IRS red tape actually helped someone. Congrats.

Comment: One way or another, you earned more of your home currency in proceeds than you paid for your house. It is very, very likely to be taxable [though not confident enough in UK tax to say so]; the main question will be whether you are allowed to consider it additional proceeds on your house [which is likely good as likely capital gains taxes would be less than regular income], or as a separate gain/income calculation.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I am neither a lawyer nor a tax-expert*

[This page on the HMRC site](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg78300p) lists several pages that appear to be relevant, starting with [CG78401 - Foreign currency: delayed remittances](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg78401) and on to [CG78408 - Foreign currency: example](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg78408) which seems pertinent to your case [paraphrased]:

> A property bought in 1983 is sold for a [taxable] gain in one tax-year (1986/87) but the proceeds cannot be released/remitted to the UK until later (1991/92), by which time currency fluctuations have created a second [taxable] gain.

The size of the first gain (selling the property) is determined by the exchange rate *in effect at the time of the sale* **but** because of local restrictions, this can be deferred.  The size of the second gain (currency movement) is determined by the change in exchange-rate between the time of the sale and the time of conversion.

In your case, the first "gain" was actually a loss, so I believe you *should* be able to use this to offset any tax due second gain.  [This page](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/losses) states that losses can be claimed up to four years after the end of the tax-year in which they were incurred, so you are probably still OK.

(The example makes application under TCGA92/S279 to defer the gain made on the original sale [because of the inability to transfer funds], but as I understand it, this is primarily to avoid a tax liability in that year.  Since you made a loss on the sale, there wouldn't have *been* a tax liability, so there would be no need to defer it).